# Where do I put the logic for a webscraper in my app and how do I trigger it when a model object is created - Django

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, logic

I am practicing Django by creating a web application where I can email in a word, the application then translates it (from eng - spanish or vice versa) and sends me a few words each day to learn.

**My problem:**
I don't know where to put the webscraper code that translates search terms and I don't know how to trigger it when a search term is received so that the result can be added to the Results model

**Models**
I have two models currently. The first model contains my search terms and the second model contains the translation results - both inherit from an abstract model with common fields:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Search(CommonInfo):
    search_term = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.search_term


class Result(CommonInfo):
    search = models.ForeignKey(
        Search,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    translation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    example = models.TextField()
    is_english = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.translation
```

**My View**
My view has a single entry point which receives an http POST request containing a parsed email from a Sendgrid parser. It extracts the word to be translated (from the subject line), then adds this to the searches model, linking it to the relevant user:

```
from vocab.models import Search

from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
import re
from users.models import CustomUser

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class Parser(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #pull out the from field
        sender = request.POST.get('from')
        #regex the actual email, turn into a string and assign to result_email
        result_email = re.search("(?<=<).*?(?=>)", sender).group(0)
        #lookup to see if it exists in the DB and throw an error if not
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=result_email).exists() == False:
            return HttpResponse("You do not have an account, please sign up first", status=401)

        #PARSING
        # parse subject
        subject = str(request.POST.get('subject'))
        # find user ID from DB
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=result_email)
        Search.objects.create(search_term=subject, user=user)
        return HttpResponse("OK")
```

**The webscraper**
I have created the outline of a web scraper that should take the searched word, create a url from it (to the SpanishDict website), it then uses BeautifulSoup to pull down a translation and example sentences:

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#creates a url from the word
def url_creator(word):
    return 'https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/' + str(word).lower()

# get request using the url
def simple_get(url):

    try: 
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                return None

    except RequestException as error:
        log_error('Error during request to %s : %s ' % (url, error))
        return None

# checks the get request response is HTML
def is_good_response(resp):

    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return (resp.status_code == 200 
            and content_type is not None
            and content_type.find('html') > -1)

# logs an error if there are any issues
def log_error(error):
    print(error)

# creates a beautiful soup object from the raw html
def bs_html_maker(raw_html):
    return BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

# finds the translation and example for the word being searched
def first_definition_finder(bs_html):
    return bs_html.find(class_="dictionary-neodict-indent-1")

# works out the language being searched (inferring it from the results of the get request)
def language_finder(bs_html):
    if bs_html.find(id="headword-and-quickdefs-es"):
        return False
    elif bs_html.find(id="headword-and-quickdefs-en"):
        return True
    else:
        raise Exception("The word you searched didn't return anything, check your spelling")

# returns  the translation, the example sentences and what language the search was in in a dictionary
def result_outputter(bs_html):
    translation_dictionary = {}
    is_english = language_finder(bs_html)
    definition_block = first_definition_finder(bs_html)
    definition = definition_block.find(class_="dictionary-neodict-translation-translation").string
    examples = examples = definition_block.find(class_="dictionary-neodict-example").strings
    example_string = "%s - %s" % (next(examples), next(examples))
    translation_dictionary["definition"] = definition
    translation_dictionary["example"] = example_string
    translation_dictionary["is_english"] = is_english
    return translation_dictionary

# pulls it all together in one method which will ideally be called whenever a search is saved to the database and the results can then be used to add the translation to the database
def vocab_translator(word):
    url = url_creator(word)
    raw_html = simple_get(url)
    bs_html = bs_html_maker(raw_html)
    return result_outputter(bs_html)
```

**My problem:**
I don't know where to put the webscraper code that translates search terms and I don't know how to trigger it when a search term is received so that the result can be added to the Results model

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Any comments on my code would also be useful as I am currently learning Django and need any feedback you can give.